# What is the value of multi-page login forms?

Tags: authentication, account-security

Various sites use a multi-page login. On the first page the user is chosen (i.e. email address), and on the second page, a password is given.

Many banks use it, Google has this also.

I first thought this could prevent phishing, but actually it would not. What makes this more secure, why are banks using it? It feels like a cargo cult to me: "they use it, we better do that too."

[Google also released info about it](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/oAsE-6wmaSU) (this is all I found):

> This new Google account sign-in flow will provide the following advantages:
>
> - Preparation for future authentication solutions that complement passwords
> - Reduced confusion among people who have multiple Google accounts
> - A better experience for SAML SSO users, such as university students or corporate users that sign in with a different identity provider than Google

But that does not seem compelling to me.